# Any way to enable “show character” in WIFI network properties?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, security

I know how to disable ' show character ' in WiFi network properties.

Now I want to enable ' show character '  because I forgot my password.

Please help

Comment: Do the opposite of disabling it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you did but another way to see the wireless password is to open an elevated command prompt (right click cmd and run as administrator and enter the following command

```
Netsh wlan show profiles name=ssid key=clear
```

Replace ssid with your network name.
The password is listed as 'Key Content' under 'Security settings'